# HttpClient error

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm tring to use http client to perform some simple snmp operations via a php script on a web server. So the php script listen to GET parameters. Here is my code:

```
 EditText host   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText port   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText community   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

                String url = "http://192.168.0.102/za/getstatus.php?host=" + host.getText().toString() + "&port=" + port.getText().toString() + "&com=" + community.getText().toString() + "&oid=" + 2 + "&port1=" + 2;
// here is my url = http://192.168.0.102/za/getstatus.php?
// host=192.168.0.101&port=10100&com=private&oid=2&port1=2

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

The response that I should get when I send the Http post is INTEGER: 0 or INTEGER: 1 so I should check that result.

Error Log when I try to send a http post:

```
12-29 06:48:21.979    1545-1545/com.example.test.test1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test.test1, PID: 1545
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
            at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.zara.sunsannici.MainActivity.selfDestruct(MainActivity.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 06:48:24.919    1545-1545/com.example.test.test1 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1545 SIG: 9
```

Maybe there is some other methods that I can use. For example in C# I use WebClient that is more easy to use and to get the returned text.

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: You can't, as the error says, use http requests (posts/get) on the main activity. Create another activity to do that or a asynctask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not make it in the UI thread

Here is an example using AsyncTask

```
EditText host   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText port   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText community   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    String url = "http://192.168.0.102/za/getstatus.php?host=" + host.getText().toString() + "&port=" + port.getText().toString() + "&com=" + community.getText().toString() + "&oid=" + 2 + "&port1=" + 2;

    new Task(url).execute();

    }

    class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HttpResponse>{
        private String url;

        Task(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Prepare a request object
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            try {
                return httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            super.onPostExecute(httpResponse);
            if(httpResponse != null){
                Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```